# OpenNMS not start

Tags: ubuntu, opennms

I install OpenNMS according to the document [install OpenNMS: Debian](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Installation:Debian) and everything is ok. But when I run`sudo service opennms start`, it just output `Starting Open Network Management System: opennms` and nothing more. I type `netstat -na | grep 8980` and there is no output.How can I check the problem?Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Logs should be written to standard out on your Ubuntu host. Check `/var/log/messages`. Also, look in `opennms.properties` for the log file location.

Comment: @Rail Thanks! I can't find /var/log/messages. I find /etc/opennms/opennms.properties. Logs are in the /var/log/opennms directory, but I can't understand. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Do the logs indicate anything? If I remember correctly, you can check status with `sudo service opennms -v status`. You can also run the `$OPENNMS_HOME/bin/opennms.sh -v status` command directly.

Comment: There should be a `daemon/output.log` file located in your `/var/log/opennms` directory which should contain startup details. Also type `ps -ef | grep java` to see if the process for opennms is running.

Comment: When I run     sudo service opennms -v status    , output is: Usage: /etc/init.d/opennms {start|stop|restart|force-reload}. The output.log is : org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.Activator] : Enabling JULI Logger API support. [Main] INFO de.novanic.eventservice.service.registry.DefaultEventRegistry - Server: Configuration changed - EventServiceConfiguration (Default Configuration) Min.: 0ms; Max.: 20000ms; Timeout: 90000ms

Comment: Try to edit the `/etc/init.d/opennms` script and see if it is delegating to another startup script when running with the `start` option. Also, have you checked the output of the `ps` command I mentioned above? `postgres` must also be running and configured. If this does not help. Please post your issue to the

Comment: I just copy the file.<br/>OPENNMS_HOME=/usr/share/opennms
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/opennms
NAME=opennms
DESC="Open Network Management System"                                                           start)
        echo -n "Starting $DESC: $NAME"
        DAEMON_MESSAGES=$($DAEMON start)
        # hide message if opennms says it's ok
        echo $OUTPUT | grep -v "Starting OpenNMS: ok"
        echo "."
        ;;

Comment: When I run ps -ef | grep java, output is:    true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.login.confi                                       g=opennms -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/usr/share/opennms/etc/jmxr                                       emote.access -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -DisThreadContextMapInher                                       itable=true -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/opennms/data/t                                       mp -jar /usr/share/opennms/lib/opennms_bootstrap.jar start

Comment: Not sure of the contents of `/usr/share/opennms`. Check if it can take `-v status` and try running it that way. Otherwise, I would post your question on `opennms-discuss@list.sourceforge.net` as this may be a specific issue with the version of Ubuntu or OpenNMS you are running.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried to access it in your browser? Also, please post code blocks in your OP above and prefix the section with `EDIT` to indicate changes to your post. It is difficult to read in comments without line breaks.

Comment: I try IP:8980/opennms and no response. I use 'code' format but it doesn't work.

Comment: Check file permissions on `/usr/sbin/opennms`. Also, run `df -h` to see if you have run out of disk space on the partition running opennms.

Comment: I run it with`root`and `/usr/sbin/opennms` is : lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Dec  2 06:03 /usr/sbin/opennms -> ../share/opennms/bin/opennms. Disk space is enough.

Comment: @Rai I installed OpenNMS in the remote host using putty terminal and output is:`opennmsStarted OpenNMS, but it has not finished starting up`. It shows error in webpage `remotehostIP:8980/opennms`.  I reinstall it on my local host and output the same thing. But this time it works in webpage `127.0.0.1:8980/opennms`. I use OpenNMS for topology discovery.

Comment: You should be able to see what the logs indicate regarding errors. Make sure that you have setup the database schema correctly and that all data is populated. You may also have issues with a daemon not starting correctly. The logs should give you an indication.

Comment: @Rai Thanks! Can OpenNMS show topology of LAN? I wonder whether I can fetch data inforamon of topology(hosts, switches and routers in the LAN) using OpenNMS. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sure. You must configure the network to discover in discovery xml file. You can specify ranges of IP addresses and exclude others. OpenNMS will then scan for these interfaces. Within pollerd config, it can also detect services running such as telnet, etc. You would most likely need to also configure services xml file. Please refer to the latest docs and good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I will find docs and try this.

Comment: @Rai I try to use `discovery` , but there is no information about `linkd`, according to link `https://www.opennms.org/wiki/Linkd` . No `linkd-configuration.xml` and no `linkd daemon` using `opennms -v status`. Thanks!

Comment: How can I start `Linkd layer 2 iso/osi model network topology discovery` using opennms?

Comment: Please post a new question. That is the appropriate way to post on stackoverflow since the original issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try 
service `opennms -v status`

or if you want to see the output of how the `opennms` daemons are being intialized you could check `/opt/opennms/logs`

do a

```
tail -f output.log
```

to check if `opennms` process is running you could try the first command further you can do a

```
ps aux | grep -i opennms
```

this should result in showing you a java process running

or when you do

```
netstat -tulnp | grep -i 8980
```

it should show you java process running on this port

Hope this helps.